# django celery error: AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module_name'

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

i am extremely new to django-celery, its doc have been confusing to me and i have been following tutorial, here is just a basic setup and i have encountered a untrackable error for me, the error is:
`AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module_name'`
full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1250, in backend
    return self._local.backend
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'backend'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 112, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 136, in on_start
    self.emit_banner()
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 170, in emit_banner
    ' \n', self.startup_info(artlines=not use_image))),
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 232, in startup_info
    results=self.app.backend.as_uri(),
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1252, in backend
    self._local.backend = new_backend = self._get_backend()
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 955, in _get_backend
    backend, url = backends.by_url(
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 69, in by_url
    return by_name(backend, loader), url
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 47, in by_name
    aliases.update(load_extension_class_names(extension_namespace))
  File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/celery/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 146, in load_extension_class_names
    yield ep.name, ':'.join([ep.module_name, ep.attrs[0]])
AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module_name'
```

the celery.py, init.py and and task are just the basic:
init.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals 

from celery import Celery

import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

app = Celery('core')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

task.py:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(bind=True)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

settings conf for celery is:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json',]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

also i have installed and added django_celery_result in INSTALLED APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'celery_practice',
    'django_celery_results'
]
```

For your information, rabbitmq-server is running on localhost thats why i have set BROKER_URL TO 'localhost':

```
 rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-03 16:14:04 PKT; 24h ago
   Main PID: 1005 (beam.smp)
     Status: "Initialized"
      Tasks: 91 (limit: 9090)
```

any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django celery error: Unrecoverable error: AttributeError("'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module\_name'")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740863/django-celery-error-unrecoverable-error-attributeerrorentrypoint-object-ha)