# AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, celery, python-importlib, kombu

I keep on getting the following error when testing a simple celery example.

```
AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
```

using the following CLI command:

```
celery -A ctest  worker --loglevel=INFO
```

The versions of the main modules I used are the following. (versions extracted from requirements.txt):

1. celery==5.2.7
2. importlib-metadata==4.13.0
3. kombu==5.2.4

And the Python version I used is 3.12

I have tried the solutions provided to this issue from links such as

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740863/django-celery-error-unrecoverable-error-attributeerrorentrypoint-object-ha/  76149751#76149751 and other fixes recommended in various links.](https://stackoverflow.com)

Fixed the version of celery as suggested. I was expecting this to resolve the issue but it did not.
`pip install celery==5.2.3`

Has anybody come across this issue?  Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

For your information, I have tracked the errors and fixed the source files' relevant lines by passing the group="value" argument where value is namespace .. etc to the entry_point method and this seems to resolve the issue, but I do not believe this is the correct way to resolve the issue. Following are the steps I took to modify the respective files.

1- FIX ONE

```
ERROR
File "/home/../.envs/.zppEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/utils/compat.py", line 82, in entrypoints
      for ep in importlib_metadata.entry_points().get(namespace, [])
```

```
SOLUTION

I modified line 82 in the ..../compat.py file and changed it from 
                 for ep in importlib_metadata.entry_points().get(namespace, [])
          to 
                 for ep in importlib_metadata.entry_points(group ='namespace')  #.get(namespace, [])
```

2- FIX TWO

```
ERROR
File "/home/../.envs/.zppEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 79, in <module>
    @with_plugins(entry_points().get('celery.commands', [])
```

```
SOLUTION
I modified line 79 in the .. bin/celery.py and changed the error line of the decorator from

@with_plugins(entry_points().get('celery.commands', [])

to
@with_plugins(entry_points(group = 'celery.commands') #.get('celery.commands', [])
```

3- FIX THREE:

```
ERROR
File "/home/../.envs/.zppEnv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 146, in load_extension_class_names
    for ep in entry_points().get().get(namespace, []):
```

```
SOLUTION
I amended the error line to the following as is the case for FIX ONE above
    for ep in importlib_metadata.entry_points(group ='namespace')  #.get(namespace, [])
```

The above three fixes seem to have resolved the issue and celery started running.

```
-------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

I am sure the above solution is not right for all sorts of reasons, please if there is something obvious I am missing let me know. I am a new starter in this area and maybe I am making the starters error.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does Celery 5.2 support Python 3.12..?

Comment: @thebjorn seems to be correct.  Python 3.12 support was rolled out with Celery 5.3. See https://pypi.org/project/celery/5.2.6/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with Python 3.12 and Celery `5.2.6`.  It looks like the first version of Celery to support Python 3.12 is `5.3.5` (which was not released when the question was first posted).

Installing Celery `>5.3.5` fixed the issue for me.